# Inno Setup: IGameExplorer and RemoveGame

Tags: inno-setup

I am using the IGameExplorer COM object to register and deregister a game with the Windows Games Explorer from within Inno Setup. While adding the game works fine, the uninstaller crashes when removing the game from the Games Explorer in the procedure "GEUnRegister"

```
OleCheck(myGEX.RemoveGame(StringToGuid(sGUID)));
```

Is this related to some error in the IGameExplorer interface, or what do I overlook? Any help is appreciated! :)

```
const
  CLSID_GameExplorer = '{9a5ea990-3034-4d6f-9128-01f3c61022bc}';
  GIS_CURRENT_USER = 2;
  GIS_ALL_USERS = 3;

type
  IGameExplorer = interface(IUnknown)
    '{E7B2FB72-D728-49B3-A5F2-18EBF5F1349E}'
    function AddGame(sGDFBinaryPath: String; sInstallDirectory: String; installScope: Word; var pguidInstanceID: TGUID): HResult;
    function RemoveGame(instanceID: TGUID): HResult;
    function UpdateGame(instanceID: TGUID): HResult;
    function VerifyAccess(sGDFBinaryPath: String; var pHasAccess: Boolean): HResult;
  end;

procedure GERegister;
var
  myGEX:   IGameExplorer;
  myGUID:  TGUID;
  o:       IUnknown;
  bAccess: Boolean;
  sGUID:   String;
begin
  o := CreateComObject(StringToGuid(CLSID_GameExplorer));
  myGEX := IGameExplorer(o);
  OleCheck(myGEX.VerifyAccess(ExpandConstant('{app}\mygame.exe'), bAccess));
  if bAccess then
  begin
    myGUID := StringToGuid('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'); 
    OleCheck(myGEX.AddGame(ExpandConstant('{app}\mygame.exe'), ExpandConstant('{app}'), GIS_ALL_USERS, myGUID));
    //write guid to registry
    sGUID := Format('{%.8x-%.4x-%.4x-%.2x%.2x-%.2x%.2x%.2x%.2x%.2x%.2x}', [myGUID.D1, myGUID.D2, myGUID.D3, myGUID.D4[0], myGUID.D4[1], myGUID.D4[2], myGUID.D4[3], myGUID.D4[4], myGUID.D4[5], myGUID.D4[6], myGUID.D4[7]]);
    RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\My Publisher\My Game',
    'ge_guid', sGUID);
  end;
end;

procedure GEUnRegister;
var
  myGEX:   IGameExplorer;
  o:       IUnknown;
  sGUID:   String;
begin
  o := CreateComObject(StringToGuid(CLSID_GameExplorer));
  myGEX := IGameExplorer(o);
  sGUID := '';
  if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\My Publisher\My Game') then
  begin
    RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\My Publisher\My Game',
      'ge_guid', sGUID);
    if sGUID <> '' then
    begin
      OleCheck(myGEX.RemoveGame(StringToGuid(sGUID)));   // <--- crashes the uninstaller
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I've got a couple of questions before I can make a suggestion.  First, what is the message of the crash?  Second, when is the GEUnRegister procedure called by the uninstaller?  One suggestion would be to add "Log" statements and then look at the Log File.  Specifically, you would want to log and track the values so that you're calling the RemoveGame with the right parameter.

Comment: I have tried calling this at usUninstall ("The application has stopped working..." and usDone (uninstaller just closes without any message). Also, when running this in the debugger, everything is fine until "OleCheck(myGEX.RemoveGame(StringToGuid(sGUID)));" and the parameter is the correct InstanceID, but the next code line is never reached. That's why I was wondering if the interface definition is faulty.

Comment: For the time being I do the de-registration using [GameuxInstallHelper.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458224/inno-setup-and-game-explorer-gameux), but I hoped to get rid of handling this helper DLL if there is a clean and easy way doing the same thing via COM. BTW, I am asking about the interface definition because I cooked that up myself - so things could have gone wrong there, naturally. :)